# Javascript function keeping last reference in loop

Tags: javascript

In the `buttons` variable I create some buttons which references a function or an object.

In loop (l.15) this `buttons` is iterated, creating an `action` reference for each one.

My problem is: When the function referenced by `action` (l.18) is called, `buttonAction` at line 19, which should referer to variable created at line 16, is always the last one in the loop, in this case, `buttons.Ok`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 1. var buttons = {
 2.     'Cancel': function () {
 3.         // stuff
 4.         },
 5.     'Ok': {
 6.     text: 'Ok',
 7.         id: 'btnOk',
 8.         click: function () {
 9.             // stuff
10.         }
11.     }
12. }
13. 
14. var buttonsMap = [];
15. for (var i in buttons) {
16.     var buttonAction = typeof buttons[i] == 'function' ? buttons[i] : buttons[i].click;
17.     var map = {
18.         action : function(arg) {
19.             buttonAction.apply(arg);
20.         }
21.     };
22.     buttonsMap.push(map);
23. }
24.
25. var instance = new Dialog({
26.     buttons : buttonsMap,
27. });
```

Comment: Read up on closures. :-) Google "javascript closure".

Comment: Thanks, @Felix. I just didn't find the correct thread. That was exactly what I was searching and already is working.